# How to retain "\r\n" (without breaking lines) in a string column when writing to csv with pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have some parquet data, with columnA of type string. An example value may be like this:

```
"ABCD \r\n DEFG \r\n XYZ"
```

So this is one record, in one column. When i display it in spark dataframe, it looks good - i can see these \r\n inside the string. I would like to write it to csv in the same form, so when I open it, I'd see:

```
"ABCD \r\n DEFG \r\n XYZ"
"ABCD \r\n DEFG \r\n XYZ"
```

My downstream user used to receive it in the above version, but now we switched to spark and there's a problem.

Instead, I get:

```
"ABCD
DEFG
XYZ"
```

I tried:

```
df2.coalesce(1).write.options(delimiter = '|', quoteAll = True, escape = "\\").csv()
```

And a couple other options, none work. I keep getting a result where the problematic records is broken into multiple lines.
I'm open to writing some UDFs, switching to pandas (if necessary, I'd prefer to stick to spark) or any other thing that may get me where I need.

Comment: Does this help? `c =  "ABCD \r\n DEFG \r\n XYZ".splitlines(False)`

Comment: There's no problem here. Everything inside the quotes is a single field value, no matter how many lines it spans. If you can't read that as a single value, the problem is in the reading code. All CSV-reading libraries can handle quoted fields easily

Comment: @toyotaSupra - I tried, it didn't change the output unfortunately

Comment: Do you want the data to have actual line breaks or do you want to escape the leading backslash so it only looks like the data has linebreaks?

Comment: Try to remove this option escape = "\\" or replace with something else like ^

Comment: You *are* writing the two ASCII characters CR and LF to the file; it's your *terminal* that *displays* them by moving the cursor instead of showing two particular glyphs.

Answer (score 1):

In case the reason isn't clear:

```py
>>> len('\n')   # single non-printable char 'new line'
1
>>> len('\\n')  # two printable chars '\' (escaped) and 'n'
2
>>>
```

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import udf                   
>>> 
>>> format_string = udf(lambda s: s.replace('\r', '\\r').replace('\n', '\\n'))
>>> 
>>> s="ABCD \r\n DEFG \r\n XYZ"
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(s,)], schema='col: string')
>>> df2 = df.withColumn('col', format_string('col'))
>>> df2.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------+
|col                    |
+-----------------------+
|ABCD \r\n DEFG \r\n XYZ|
+-----------------------+

>>> df2.write.csv('csv_newline', header=True)
>>>
```

```
$ cat csv_newline/part-0000*.csv
col
ABCD \r\n DEFG \r\n XYZ
$
```

Comment: Cool, this is exactly what I need! Thank you. Can you please help me understand why it works? How come when I do df.show and df2.show I see the same things - i.e. signle slashes only

Comment: Updated the post to add a little more explanation. You don't really care what `show()` prints (PS: it clearly escapes non-printable chars, to make output look tabular), you care how `CsvWriter` treats them. What you need to do is what `show()` is doing.